# Python run a command with arguments containing backslash and double quotes with subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I need to pipe an `echo` and a `egrep` within a python script, I saw some solutions elsewhere but I am still blocked because my regular expression pattern contain backslash and double quotes that are strangely transmitted from python to the command.

`seq` is just a dumb example for the post, the regular expression pattern can also be longer.

```py
import string
import subprocess

seq = ['a','b','c']

ps = subprocess.Popen(('echo', '""'.join(seq)), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = subprocess.check_output(('egrep', '"([a-z])\1{2,}"'), stdin=ps.stdout)
ps.wait()
```

I got the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tst.py", line 8, in <module>
    output = subprocess.check_output(('egrep', '"([a-z])\1{2,}"'), stdin=ps.stdout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 356, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 438, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '('egrep', '"([a-z])\x01{2,}"')' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

We can saw on the last line that the `\` is misinterpreted.

I also tried `'"([a-z])\\1{2,}"'` and `r'"([a-z])\1{2,}"'` but it does not work better...

Comment: Have you checked if your command works in the console?

Comment: returned status 1 means that the pattern was not found by egrep not that your command is not working beucase of a syntax or something like that

Comment: What's the `stdout`?

Comment: @absolutelydevastated yes it works

Comment: @geckos I know but the command don't work because the regexp pattern is wrongly transmitted, look the error message, the regexp pattern transmitted to egrep is `'"([a-z])\x01{2,}"'`. Not the thing that I have tipped in my script

Comment: This shows the expected command `subprocess.check_output(r'sh -x egrep "([a-z])\1{2,}"', shell=True)`

Comment: `+ exec grep -E '([a-z])\1{2,}'`

Comment: If you print the `STDOUT` of `echo` with `print(ps.stdout.read())` then you can see the Input of `egrep` is `a""b""c`. It is the expected input for `egrep`?